# How to see a code preview (in Experimental`Explore[] or related GUI)

Tags: graphics, manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction, hold

I have been messing around with built in `` Experimental`Explore[] `` function. You can call the function in *Mathematica* yourself to see what it looks like. It is a GUI that allows you to change plot options to see how they affect a graph.

I find the idea very useful in helping somehow learn how to code graphs as they can see the graph and code next to each other.  The user can immediately see how the code changes as they add and subtract options visually using the GUI.

`` Experimental`Explore[] `` is broken but parts of it still work.  I am now building my own.  One part that I am interested in keeping is the code preview panel that updates with current code on the fly (as you can see in the bottom left in pic below.)

[image]

Here is some code I am trying to add to to get the code preview window but not sure how to get started.  Ideas?

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3},
  AxesLabel -> {xlabel, ylabel},
  Ticks -> {tics, tics}],
 Control[{{tics, Automatic, ""}, {Automatic -> "A", None -> "0"}}],
 Control[{{xlabel, "x", ""}, InputField, ImageSize -> {24, 24}}], 
 Control[{{ylabel, "y", ""}, InputField, ImageSize -> {24, 24}}]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quick fix is to use e.g. `Inactivate` and friends:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
     Activate @ #, 
     Panel @ ExpressionCell[
         # /. Inactive -> Defer, 
         "Notebook", "Input"
     ]
 }] & @ Inactivate @ Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, 
     AxesLabel -> {xlabel, ylabel}, Ticks -> {tics, tics}]
 , 
 Control[{{tics, Automatic, ""}, {Automatic -> "A", None -> "0"}}], 
 Control[{{xlabel, "x", ""}, InputField, ImageSize -> {24, 24}}], 
 Control[{{ylabel, "y", ""}, InputField, ImageSize -> {24, 24}}]]
```

[image]