# How to make the result of InputForm balance the bracket

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, output, format

I always use `InputForm` to check the result object,such as `Dataset` or `Graphics` or other objects.But if you are in the result of `InputForm`,you cannot use the Front-End function of balance the bracket. Note this gif

[image]

When I double click the input line, I will select all content just in this bracket.But when I'm in result of `InputForm`,I will select all line. Of course I can copy the output of `InputForm` as another new input,but which will make the notebook more mess.

Any method can make the output of `InputForm` support the function of balance the bracket?

Comment: Use expr //InputForm //SequenceForm

Comment: @CarlWoll Fun,that is a workaround deserved to be accepted..Thanks very very much...

Comment: I tend to use `output // InputForm // List`. Although it adds an extra pair of enclosing braces, I find it a small price to pay to use those features you desire.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes,I'd like to use your solution.Thanks.Of course,`output // InputForm // f` is enogh for me.

Comment: Strongly related: [(a/55545)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks,that's a very good link. :)

Comment: Just a point on what's actually going on to cause this: `InputForm` creates a `Cell` with a `String` as its cell content, instead of `BoxData` and the front-end only provides many features on boxes. It's worth noting as you might see other odd behaviors like this and wonder why they occur and that distinction might explain them. That also means you can go into the `Cell` and stick a `BoxData` before the content, too, and get your boxes back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per my comment, I like using `expr //InputForm //SequenceForm`, but another similar possibility is to use a custom head with a custom [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule. For instance, let's call the custom form `myInputForm`. Then, we can define:

```
myInputForm /: MakeBoxes[myInputForm[expr_], StandardForm] := MakeBoxes[InputForm[expr]]
```

We also need to add `myInputForm` to $OutputForms:

```
Unprotect[$OutputForms];

AppendTo[$OutputForms, myInputForm];

Protect[$OutputForms];
```

Now, `myInputForm` gets stripped before being stored in [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out). For instance:

```
Interpolation[{1,2,3,4}]
% //myInputForm
% //Head
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 4}}, <>]
>
> InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 4}}, {
>     5, 3, 0, {4}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{
>     1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {Automatic}]
>
> InterpolatingFunction

Answer (score 14):

If you have Version 11 you can use the function `PrettyForm` instead of processing `InputForm` output to get the desired result:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 4}] // PrettyForm
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Range[5]^2] // PrettyForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For earlier versions you can also wrap `InputForm` with `DisplayForm`:

```
ListLinePlot[Range[5]^2] // InputForm // DisplayForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well,I learn a ton of *Form today.Thanks. :)

Comment: @yode, does `PrettyForm` work in your desktop version? if not i I will delete that part.

Comment: @kglr it does, nice find.

Answer (score 9):

Carl's tip seems to be the best quick solution.

Very often I find syntax/style highlighting very useful too so I use:

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[InputForm@#, "Input"]] &
```

to get everything what Input cells offer:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 1
] // CellPrint[ExpressionCell[InputForm@#, "Input"]] &
```

[image]

related:

[How to see a code preview (in Experimental`Explore[] or related GUI)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102938/5478)

[How to use an ExpressionCell to display e.g. an Input cell inside a generated output?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103257/5478)

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this because of the combination of `CellPrint` and the `"Input"` style.  This creates Input cells which have `GeneratedCell->True` and `CellAutoOverwrite->True` (this is documented behavior of `CellPrint`).  If you start using these cells for real, then you may have unpleasant side effects...like your Input cells disappearing when you evaluate inputs above them.  If you really want Input cells, I'd recommend a `NotebookWrite` based solution.  The equivalent formulation would be `NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  Cell[BoxData[ToString[#, InputForm]], "Input"]] &`.

Comment: @JohnFultz valid points but wasn't the problem for me so far as I used it only for preview or manual gutting.

Comment: Many (many, *many*) years ago, we made a big mistake and had cells written by `NotebookWrite` have `GeneratedCell->True`.  It caused a whole class of mysterious-to-our-users bugs where cells would just seem to "randomly" disappear after evaluation and data was getting lost.  It took quite a long time after we fixed `NotebookWrite` to stop seeing user reports like this.  So, hopefully, you'll understand my sensitivity about the subject.