# How to link Manipulate to specific questions to activate sliders

Tags: manipulate, programming, code-request

I have the following multiplication `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
   x*y,
   {x, 1, 10},
   {y, 5, 15}
              ];
```

When you run this `Manipulate`, the X and Y sliders should not be visible to the user. But, The question: What is your X value between 1 and 10? should pop up with an empty box for entering a number for X between 1 and 10. After entering an X value, then the second question: What is your Y value between 5 and 15? should pop up with another empty box for entering a Y value. After answering both questions, the answer should be visible in `Manipulate` pane. Every time you run this `Manipulate`, the same steps should be evoked.

Can we do that in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** For the revised question, as described it is not clear why you want a [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) as opposed to using [`Input`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Input.html).

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using [`Slider`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html)

```
Panel[
 x = 0;
 y = 0;
 result = {};
 While[Not[IntegerQ[x] && 1 <= x <= 10], 
  (x = Input[
     "What is your X value between 1 and 10?"])];
 While[Not[IntegerQ[y] && 5 <= y <= 15],
  (y = Input[
     "What is your Y value between 5 and 15?"])];
 result = x*y;
 If[result === {}, "",
  Manipulate[
   xx*yy,
   {{xx, x, "x"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{yy, y, "y"}, 5, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]], 
 "Product of X and Y"]
```

Or using [`SetterBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html)

```
Panel[
 x = 0;
 y = 0;
 result = {};
 While[Not[IntegerQ[x] && 1 <= x <= 10], (x = Input[
     "What is your X value between 1 and 10?"])];
 While[Not[IntegerQ[y] && 5 <= y <= 15],
  (y = Input[
     "What is your Y value between 5 and 15?"])];
 result = x*y;
 If[result === {}, "",
  Manipulate[
   xx*yy,
   {{xx, x, "x"}, Range[10], ControlType -> SetterBar},
   {{yy, y, "y"}, Range[5, 15], ControlType -> SetterBar}]],
 "Product of X and Y"]
```

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER.**

Instead of a [`Slider`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html) you should consider using a [`PopupMenu`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupMenu.html) to choose amongst alternatives.

Define a list of countries

```
countries = CountryData[#, "Name"] & /@
   CountryData["SouthAmerica"];
```

Define a list of sectors (shortened here)

```
sectors = {
   "AGF: Agriculture/hunting/fishery",
   "CO12: Crude oil/mining",
   "MA1: Manufacturing/petroleum refining",
   "MA2: Manufacturing-other"};

Manipulate[
 {country, sector},
 {{country, 1, "Choose a country"}, 
  Thread[Range[Length[countries]] -> countries], ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 {{sector, 1, "Choose a sector for targeting"}, 
  Thread[Range[Length[sectors]] -> sectors], ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is a very useful comment to improve the appearance of the `Manipulate` window.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works the way I expected. Since I already have various standalone `Manipulate` codes involving heavy computations, I would like to stick to those instead of revising them with your proposal. It is a kind of `path dependency` problem. In your edited answer above, would it be possible to see the final product `X*Y` within the original `Manipulate` pane showing X and Y sliders for the user to continue choosing new values from the sliders, instead of running the code again?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It is what I was imagining. Referring to your earlier comment above, would it be possible to enter input X and Y values by using a Popup` menu? After the first question, a `Popup` menu comes and the choice is made. Then, the second question comes with a `Popup` menu. After both choices are made, the `Manipulate` becomes visible. Just like you did above, only difference is to use the `Popup` menu. I hope I am not asking too much. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the example using `SetterBar` change both instances of `SetterBar` to `PopupMenu`. However, both questions must be answered in the input fields before the `Manipulate` will appear. If you only want `PopupMenu`s, then use a straightforward `Manipulate` as in the original extended comment.

Comment: Thanks very much for this nice piece.

Answer (score 2):

Slider is best for adjust Reals. SetterBar is nice to Integer.

Like everything else a lot is a matter of taste. Some like it more individualizable.

```
Manipulate[
 Which[typeSelected == 1, Row[{"Product of x * y = ", x*y}], 
  typeSelected == 2, Row[{"Product x * y =  ", x*y}], True, 
  "No way ! Please report a bug"], 
 Grid[{{Style["Selection of x and y", 10], SpanFromLeft}, {"Select", 
    TabView[{{1, 
       "x" -> Row[{"x= ", 
          SetterBar[Dynamic[x, {x = #} &], Range[10]]}]}, {2, 
       "y" -> Row[{"y= ", 
          SetterBar[Dynamic[y, {y = #} &], Range[11] + 4], 
          Dynamic[y]}]}}, Dynamic[typeSelected]]}}, Frame -> All, 
  Spacings -> .5, FrameStyle -> Gray], {{x, 1}, None}, {{y, 1}, 
  None}, {{typeSelected, 1}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {x, y, typeSelected}]
```

[image: Manipulate with nice layout]

Some nice too is:

```
{Slider2D[Dynamic[y], {{1, 5}, {10, 15}, {1, 1}}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"], Dynamic[y[[1]]*y[[2]]]}
```

[image: Slider2D labeled]

A more sophisticated example:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {3, 7}}, {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[], 
    GridLines -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
       10, 11, 12, 13, 14}}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {5, 15}}]], Dynamic[Round@pt], 
  Dynamic[Round@pt[[1]] Round@pt[[2]]]}]
```

[image: DynamicModule with a Plot background with GridLines]

Somehow Wolfram Inc. is working on Manipulate still. Have a look at

[`Experimental`Explore[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102938/how-to-see-a-code-preview-in-experimentalexplore-or-related-gui)

Comment: Thank you for your variety of codes. I will keep them in my repository for more advanced work.